# Matching Whitespaces Within Java's Regex

Tags: java, regex, validation

I'm creating a telephone application in Java, and need to be able to validate whether a telephone number fits one of these formats:

- `444 444 4444`
- `444-444-4444`
- `4444444444`

To accomplish this task, I wrote this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.next();
    System.out.print(str.matches("\\d{3}([-. ])?\\d{3}([-. ])?\\d{4}"));
}
```

For some reason, the String method `matches()` works perfectly for `444-444-4444` and `4444444444`, but returns an incorrect answer when I input `444 444 4444`. I've taken a look at several similar questions on stack overflow, but I still haven't found a fix that works correctly for my problem. Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Try with `\\s` instead of (space)

Comment: How strict do you want the validation to be? Are `123123-1234` or `123-123 1234` accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is fine: http://ideone.com/Y4Hlph

The problem is that [`Scanner#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) returns [whitespace-delimited tokens by default,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) since you haven't otherwise specified the delimiter.

> A `Scanner` breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

Use [`Scanner#nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) if you want to get input line-by-line.
 http://ideone.com/O3Hu0Z

Comment: Oh god I feel like such an idiot now. it's always these dumb mistakes Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your regex pattern but rather with the actual `String` being passed in.

[Scanner#next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) uses a whitespace as a delimiter so only passes in the first `4444` token when you use `444 444 4444` as the input value. You could use

```
String str = sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is not your regex but how you are reading in your string. `Scanner#next()` returns the next token it find and splits tokens on delimiters, *whitespace is the delimiter by default*.

Try using `Scanner#nextLine()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Scanner.nextLine()` to delimit by newlines, not just any whitespace character. With `next()`, you get "444" for the third case.

Be wary that the dot "." matches any character.

The correct regexp would therefore look like this:

`\\d{3}([- ])?\\d{3}([- ])?\\d{4}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 String str ="444 444 4444";
System.out.print(str.matches("\\d{3}([-. ])?\\d{3}([-. ])?\\d{4}"));
```

there is no problem in your code.just add

```
String str=sc.nextLine();
```